# Using linq to pass through every row of a table and change data?

Tags: c#, linq

So I want to go through a list of rows, change all the ID of every member of the table to the iteration number

```
public class modelOne
{
    public ID;
    ... //more data added
}
public class oneDbContext : DbContext
{
    public DbContext() : base("DataBase")
    {

    }

    public DbSet<modelOne> Model{ get; set; }

}


oneDbContext db = new oneDbContext();
for(i=1; i <= db.Model.Count(); i++)
{
   db.Model.ID = i; //Do it for every row in the table
}
db.SaveChanges();
```

Is it possible to do that? How can I achieve this?

**UPDATE**

Edited so I could clarify some things

Comment: This code does not make any sense. What is `Collection`. Is it a table in your database? How many rows are we talking about?

Comment: Need more info - questions is very confusing.

Comment: @KosalaW Sorry! I updated the code, is it clearer now?

Comment: @Pure.Krome Sorry! I updated the code, is it clearer now?

Comment: How many records are you talking about here? Is it 10-15 rows, or 1000000 rows?

Comment: @KosalaW no more than 100 for sure

Comment: I am more interested to know whether it is less than 1000 or not.

Comment: If `ID` is the primary key in the table this will not work.  It looks like you're trying to reset a primary key (possible auto-increment) to a consecutive number which is a bad idea.

Comment: @DStanley but can I do this with an aux value? What I'm trying to do is, say I have 5 rows in the table (Ids 1 to 5) and delete the 4th, i want the new ids to be 1, 2, 3, 4 instead of 1, 2, 3, 5.

Comment: @KosalaW it is, for sure.

Comment: @n.ab Not with EF.  EF has to know the primary key to know which record to update.  If you change the primary key value then it will update the wrong record.  Even if you _could_ , changing the primary key is a bad idea.  I would suggest you learn to live with gaps in the ID.  If you have a specific need for them to be consecutive then update your question.

Comment: @DStanley But can it be done with a new field in the table that keeps it constantly consecutive? Say a field we have a variable that keeps count of that, when I delete a row, can I update my whole table with new values for this variable? If so, how can that be done?

Comment: @n.ab add an extra value that can have continuous numbers. Don't go changing the ID's. Why do you need all consecutive numbers though? I can't see the use-case :)

Comment: @n.ab If you need a consecutive number, you need to make sure your ID column is an `Identity` column in your database. If this is a "one-time" job, you should use SQL to do this.

Comment: @Stefanvds Haha, I'm still new to programming, even though I have done several things, but, I hava a code that does infinite scroll with jquery, and it calls a controller to get how many elements from the database, this function uses the id to get the values, theres two variables that does that ( fromNumber and toNumber), so if there is a gap in those values, the function stops working

Comment: @n.ab. So what happens when someone deletes a record? How do you prevent that?

Comment: @KosalaW That'S what I'm trying to sort out, if a row is deleted and the sequence is broken, I need a way to make it consecutive again so my jquery function can work, so i thought about going through the rows and updating it to consecutive numbers

Comment: @n.ab Ok. Have a look at my answer. It should help you in that case.

Comment: @n.ab that sounds like a bad function. find a better one. Usually it'll do something like Linq Skip(100).Take(50) to get this result. It should not look at ID's. What if you are using Guids for IDs

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming that you have less than 1000 rows, you can do it this way.

```
var count = db.Model.Count();
for(int i = 0; i < count; i++)
{
    var model = db.Model.ElementAt(i);
    model.ID = i;
}
db.SaveChanges();
```

But if you have more than 1000 (this is not a hardcore limit) rows, then you have to make sure to call `db.SaveChanges` every 1000 rows or so.

Comment: As others have pointed out, I can't "redefine" the primary key, but I was able to use your code perfectly when using an auxiliar variable to keep everything the way I wanted. Thanks! Edit: The only thing is that I needed to use this line instead of just `ElementAt(i)`: `var model = db.Model.OrderByDescending(p => p.Aux).Skip(i).FirstOrDefault();`